# Make Sub-array in Array in Codesys?

Tags: syntax, codesys

I am trying to manipulate a sub-array of an existing array. Can Codesys do this? I guess this is more of a syntax question.

In Python, there is `slice()` is there a Codesys equivalent?

Here's some pseudocode of what I am trying to do

```
VAR
    Array1: ARRAY [1..3, 1..3] OF BOOL;
    Statement: BOOL;
END_VAR

IF
    Statement := TRUE
THEN
    Array1[1,1..3] :=TRUE;
END_IF
```

[1,1..3] or [1,1:3] are not valid syntax. What is the appropriate way to access multiple cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set single value to a range of array elements. Syntax `[1,1..3]` or `[1,1:3]` will not work. You can only access one element at a time.

```
Array1[1,1] := TRUE;
Array1[1,2] := TRUE;
Array1[1,3] := TRUE;
```

Or

```
Array1[1,1] := Array1[1,2] := Array1[1,3] := Statement;
```